# Javascript preprocessor to replace variable reference during build

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, yeoman, grunt-usemin

Is there a way to substitute variables in javascript files, with a preprocessor during build process. I uses grunt, usemin, uglifyjs (part of yeoman stack).

I currently refer to `url` from a global javascript object. For example,

```
 my.url = {
     book: {
        get : '/my/book/{id},
        new: '/my/book'

     }
 }
```

in my program, I may refer the `url` as `my.url.book.get`, etc. The intention is

- do not want the url string spread across the program, as any change during development make it hard to refactor.
- url may generate based on the server API, and don't want to duplicate in client.

Now, once I am happy with the development, I like to preprocess all the javascript file to substitute all these references to actual url string. Intention is to avoid loading an extra file with all the url (may the user only need few of the url).

is there any tool, similar to html templating package, to process the javascript and replace all the variables. I prefer if it works with grunt/yeoman stack.

Comment: You can run most js through the C preprocessor without a problem. A bit hacky, but it works.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I never used it and if it is node/grunt based, I can integrate it easily with my workflow. Anyway, if there is no other way, I will look into it.

Comment: Why don't you simply provide a "facade" module that holds methods like `getBook()`. Not only would this improve readability but maintainability as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with [grunt-replace](https://github.com/outaTiME/grunt-replace) It allows for all kinds of string substitutions in text files. I use it to sync version numbers in `bower.json`, `package.json` etc, but obviously you can use it for source file value substitutions as well.

That said, in *your* case I'd definitely opt for a more dynamic solution with env variables, with for instance [grunt-env](https://github.com/jsoverson/grunt-env).

Answer (score 0):

Try *@Builder* https://github.com/electricimp/Builder

Little example

in **config.js**:

```
@set apiEndpoint "https://somesite.com/api/v1"
```

then:

```
@include once "config.js"
let url = "@{apiEndpoint}"
```

Comment: I strongly recommend you read [How to offer personal open-source libraries?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/229085) if you want to post about your own projects here.